# How to make object symmetrical?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, sculpting

I have a sculpted object which was edited manually in edit mode. Since than the symmetry was broken. I want to make the object symmetrical, but since it was a sculpted object it was not idencical geometry on both side because of the dynatopo. There is no an edge loop on the symmetry plane.

[image]
So I can't select the left or right side properly to delete and use the mirror modifier.

How to make an object like this symmetrical?

To prevent this issue: is there a way to do transforms (transform, rotation, scale) symmetrical in edit mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, in the *Tools* panel (on the left of the 3D view), in the *Dyntopo* menu, click on the *Symmetrize* button, but before that, above this button, make sure you've chosen the right axis. And also remember that the object origin will be the middle of the symmetrize effect.

[image]